# Does VPN affect all logged-in users in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, user-accounts

If one user activates a VPN connection, and then another user does "switch user" and logs in, are they now also using the VPN or does W7 confine it to the account which actually started the program?

Comment: i was going to test it, with screenshots. But i'm too lazy, and decided you can test it for me.

Comment: I don't have a VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a VPN on one account will in fact pull other active accounts into it.